# how to split a file into smaller files (one file per line) [split doesn't work]

Tags: bash, split

I'm trying to split a very large file to one new file per line.

Why? It's going to be input for Mahout. but there are too many lines and not enough suffixes for split.

Is there a way to do this in bash?

Comment: I had just tried split without any arguments. new to bash so experimenting. 

split --lines=1 file.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Increase Your Suffix Length with Split

If you insist on using split, then you have to increase your suffix length. For example, assuming you have 10,000 lines in your file:

```
split --suffix-length=5 --lines=1 foo.txt
```

If you really want to go nuts with this approach, you can even set the suffix length dynamically with the *wc* command and some shell arithmetic. For example:

```
file='foo.txt'
split \
    --suffix-length=$(( $(wc --chars < <(wc --lines < "$file")) - 1 )) \
    --lines=1 \
    "$file"
```

### Use Xargs Instead

However, the above is really just a kludge anyway. A more correct solution would be to use *xargs* from the GNU findutils package to invoke some command once per line. For example:

```
xargs --max-lines=1 --arg-file=foo.txt your_command
```

This will pass one line at a time to your command. This is a much more flexible approach and will dramatically reduce your disk I/O.

Comment: You're assuming that each line is to be accessed independently. It's entirely possible that the input program really needs thousands of independent files all sitting on the disk, to be accessed at random.

Comment: that's pretty cool, how can I use xargs to say print one line a a time?

Comment: just tried xargs --max-lines=1 --arg-file=foo.txt echo

but that only prints the first two lines of the file for some reason...

Comment: @user1745713 *echo* may be a shell built-in. It works for me as `xargs --max-lines=1 --arg-file=foo.txt /bin/echo`. Note the path to the binary rather than the use of the shell built-in.

Answer (score 2):

```
split --lines=1 --suffix-length=5 input.txt output.
```

This will use 5 characters per suffix, which is enough for 26<sup>5</sup> = 11881376 files. If you really have more than that, increase suffix-length.

Comment: quick follow up. can you specify the output dir to be different by just adding a path on the output like so:

split --lines=1 --suffix-length=5 input.txt output/file.

Comment: Yes, that will work.  split is going to use whatever prefix you type as a literal string.  output dir should exist before running split.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do something for each line:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    do_something_with "$line"
done < big.file
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel can do this:

```
cat big.file | parallel --pipe -N1 'cat > {#}'
```

But if Mahout can read from stdin then you can avoid the temporary files:

```
cat big.file | parallel --pipe -N1 mahout --input-file -
```

Learn more about GNU Parallel https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1 and walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html